# MFC/C++: Setting property BS_OWNERDRAW to checkbox button doesn't work

Tags: c++, winapi, checkbox, mfc, ownerdrawn

I am trying to change draw context (background color, text color, icon, ...)  of checkbox button dynamically, but I have several problems to draw it, because when I try to modify style in `PreSubclassWindow` callback, the framework doesn't paint the checkbox control.

```
void CheckBoxButton::PreSubclassWindow()
{
   ModifyStyle(0xf, BS_CHECKBOX);
   ModifyStyle(0, BS_OWNERDRAW);

   CButton::PreSubclassWindow();
}
```

Also see implemented code according to proposals below:

```
void CheckBoxButton::paint()
    {
        HTHEME theme;
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(rect);

        theme = OpenThemeData(this->GetSafeHwnd(), L"Button");
        HRESULT result = DrawThemeBackground(theme, GetDC()->GetSafeHdc(), BP_CHECKBOX, CBS_CHECKEDDISABLED, &rect, NULL);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `BS_OWNERDRAW` style can not be combined with other styles. From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951(v=vs.85).aspx):

> **BS_OWNERDRAW**
>
> Creates an owner-drawn button. The owner window receives a WM_DRAWITEM message when a visual aspect of the button has changed. Do not combine the BS_OWNERDRAW style with any other button styles.

Comment: Are there any way to change checkbox draw context without setting `BS_OWNERDRAW` property?

Comment: @AlbertoBricio It seems like you can either let the system draw the button or draw everything manually using `DrawThemeBackground` whenever you want to keep system look on some elements.

Comment: Ok, I am calling `DrawThemeBackgroundFunction` once I call `Create(...)` function and result is `S_OK`, nevertheless I cannot see if there have been changes on button control style...

Comment: Please, you can see my new code on question description

Comment: @AlbertoBricio It is strange that attempt to draw both check and unchecked styles at the same time succeeds.

Comment: you're right nevertheless it doesn't work although I set only `CBS_CHECKEDDISABLED` state...

Comment: I guess you should create another question with detailed description of how you are drawing it. Right now it is not clear how this function is invoked. I would expect paint function to receive hdc instead of calling `GetDC` (are you actually getting window dc?), you also don't seem to validate the window afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

`BS_CHECKBOX` (hex:02, bin:0010) and `BS_OWNERDRAW` (hex:0B, bin:1011) are mutually exclusive, which you can already see by looking at their binary representations (the bits overlap).

Alternatively you can use *custom draw*, which doesn't require the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style, it works by responding to the [custom draw notifications only](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761847(v=vs.85).aspx). So you can keep `BS_CHECKBOX` and let the system draw some aspects of the checkbox.